# WebView and shouldOverrideUrlLoading

Tags: android, webview

My code:

```
    public class View_WebView extends Activity  {
    WebView myWebView;

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.endsWith(".mp4")){
            Intent in = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(in);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());      
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://hdcast.pl");
    }     

}


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 />
```

Eclipse compiles correctly, when I launch my application on my smartphone I got an error:

"Unfortunately, the application XX has been stopped"

Comment: will you please post your logcat?

Comment: The entrance to my smartphone is damaged...

Comment: can you show the logcat here ..

Comment: http://hdcast.pl/ss.png

Comment: Sorry - bad link.  http://hdcast.pl/log.txt

Answer (score 1):

Your webView is null, uncomment this line:

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Edit:

You also must have a WebView element in your XML

```
 <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 />
```

Comment: yes...this is the main cause which must gives nullpointer here..+1 for finding the main issue..

Comment: Remember to add the webview to your xml, see my edit

Comment: compile correctly, but on my smartphone is error still, new code is in my first post

Comment: "Unfortunately, the application XX has been stopped" and application is closed

Answer (score 1):

You are not using it correctly!

You have to make your own custom WebClient that will extend the WebClient and inside there make use of shouldOverrideUrlLoading under your needs.

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith(".mp4")){
        Intent in = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(in);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you add your custom WebClient to your WebView and you are good to go.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());      
myWebView.loadUrl("XXX");
```

EDIT:As per the previous answer though, make sure that you are initializing your WebView with `findViewById()`

Answer (score 1):

Do it directly :

From this [tutorial](http://www.catchingtales.com/android-webview-shouldoverrideurlloading-and-redirect/416/)

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
@Override  
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {  
 if (url.endsWith(".mp4")){
    Intent in = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(in);
    return true;
}
else
    return false;
}
```